# Работа regex_search

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

1. Как работает функция `regex_search()`? Допустим, есть строка «1 2 3 4». Нужно вывести каждую цифру с новой строки.
2. И ещё, есть строка кода `regex rx("\\d");` Как `rx` переопределить на другое регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:
1)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <regex>

    int main (){
        std::string s ("1 2 3 4");
        std::smatch m;
        std::regex e ("\\d"); 


        while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
            std::cout << m[0] << " ";
            s = m.suffix().str();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

2)

```
    rx = "\\d+";
```

Comment: А что делает вызов m.suffix() ? И как, например, искать с определённой позиции в строке?

Comment: @Bill, _Returns a reference to a sub_match object representing the character sequence that follows the end of the matched sequence in the target sequence._ Если в двух словах, то возвращает то, что идет после совпадения. Если не понятно, на словах, можете в моем примере дописать `std::cout << m.suffix().str();` и посмотреть что получится

Comment: @Bill, для того, чтобы искать в подстроке, можете использовать версию `regex_search` с итераторами, выглядеть будет примерно так `std::regex_search (s.cbegin(), s.cend(), m, e)`. Вместо `s.cbegin()` и `s.cend()` передавайте пару итераторов, между которыми находится интересующая вас подстрока